# Converting seconds to Mins, Hours and days

Tags: c#, winforms

We've recently covered "if statements etc..." in my class and I'm having trouble with this question. (Apologies for my poor english)

This is the question:

- Create an application that lets the user enter a number of seconds and works as follows:
- There are 60 seconds in a minute. If the number of seconds entered by the user
  is greater than or equal to 60, the program should display the number of minutes
  in that many seconds.
- There are 3,600 seconds in an hour. If the number of seconds entered by the
  user is greater than or equal to 3,600, the program should display the number
  of hours in that many seconds.
- There are 86,400 seconds in a day. If the number of seconds entered by the user
  is greater than or equal to 86,400, the program should display the number of
  days in that many seconds.

And this is my answer full of mistakes:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
            //Declaring Variables
            int totalSeconds;
            int hours;
            int minutes;
            int minutesRemainder;
            int hoursRemainderMinutes;
            int hoursRemainderSeconds;

            // Parsing and calculations

            totalSeconds = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
            minutesRemainder = totalSeconds % 60;
            hours = minutes / 60;
            hoursRemainderMinutes = minutes % 60;
            hoursRemainderSeconds = hoursRemainderMinutes % 60;

            if (totalSeconds >= 60)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(totalSeconds.ToString());
            }

            else if (totalSeconds >= 3600)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(minutes.ToString() + " minutes, " + minutesRemainder.ToString() + " seconds");
            }

            else if (totalSeconds >= 84600)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(hours.ToString() + " hours, " + hoursRemainderMinutes.ToString() + " minutes, " + hoursRemainderSeconds.ToString() + " seconds");


        }
    }
}
```

}

When run, my program doesn't calculate anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have a look at `TimeSpan`

Comment: I would guess he's not allowed/supposed to use a library, but do the calculations himself, as this is for a class

Comment: This looks like homework. I don't know how your teacher will react if you hand in a program that uses [TimeSpan.FromSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Jonesopolis TimeSpan isn't a library. It's a built-in .NET type. It's obvious that the teacher/tutor wants the OP to work the problem, but ...

Comment: Assuming you're using Visual Studio: what happens if you press F9 in the IDE if the cursor is on  `totalSeconds = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);` and then hit F5 (run in the debugger) click your button and then step on each line, inspecting the values?

Comment: Umm we haven't covered timespans yet. I believe that we're supposed to do the calculations by ourselves

Comment: Well for starters your `if` statements are wrong.  You display seconds when it should be minutes and then minutes when it should be hours, and then hours when it should display days.

Comment: @juharr Oh yeah. Thanks >.<! I'm such an idiot....

Comment: @MelanieTurner Actually your first `if` will catch everything.  You need to do `<` instead of `>=` or you need to start with the highest values first and work down to the smaller ones.

Comment: @juharr Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

You should use [TimeSpan.FromSeconds method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds(v=vs.110).aspx).

It will give you `TimeSpan` structure instance where you have access to:

- `TotalDays`
- `TotalHours`
- `TotalMinutes`

properties.

**Edit**

They say in comments that you want to achieve that without using any libraries.
Then the approach would be (in terms of your taks):

```
int totalSeconds = ....;///
int totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
int totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
int totalDays = totalHours / 24;

if (totalDays > 0){
 //show days
} else if (totalHours > 0){
  //show hours
} else if (totalMinutes > 0){
  //show minutes
} else {
  //show seconds
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote, when `FromSeconds` is the method that should be used in any production code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir but I'm afraid we aren't allowed to use Timespan as we haven't been taught about it yet.

Comment: @MelanieTurner, I understand. I updated my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Ok.  Let's assume you don't want to use a TimeSpan.  Your code is pretty close to be working.  Your problem is that your last "else if" statement should be inversed with the if statement like this :

```
if (totalSeconds >= 86400)
{
    Console.WriteLine(days.ToString() " days," + hours.ToString() + " hours, " + hoursRemainderMinutes.ToString() + " minutes, " + hoursRemainderSeconds.ToString() + " seconds");
}
else if (totalSeconds >= 3600)
{
    Console.WriteLine(hours.ToString() + " hours, " + hoursRemainderMinutes.ToString() + " minutes, " + hoursRemainderSeconds.ToString() + " seconds");
}
else if (totalSeconds >= 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine(minutes.ToString() + " minutes, " + minutesRemainder.ToString() + " seconds");
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine(totalSeconds.ToString());
}
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: This is close, but for 84600 it should be days and then 3600 should be hours and 60 should be minutes and then a final else would just be seconds.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan is the easiest way to go.

```
        int Input = 32453; //Amount of seconds 
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, Input); //3 constructor arguments are (Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
        if (ts.Days > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ts.Days + " Day(s)");
        }
        else if (ts.Hours > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ts.Hours + " Hour(s)");
        }
        else if (ts.Minutes > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ts.Minutes + " Minute(s)");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ts.Seconds + " Second(s)");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: It's been stated that the OP is not suppose to use `TimeSpan` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can calculate all the values and determine which ones need to be in the output

```
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
int totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
int minutes = totalMinutes % 60;
int totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
int hours = totalHours % 24;
int totalDays = totalHours / 24;

if (totalDays > 0)
{
    Console.Write(totalDays + " Days ");
}
if (totalHours > 0)
{
    Console.Write(hours + " Hours ");
}
if (totalMinutes > 0)
{
    Console.Write(minutes + " Minutes ");
}

Console.WriteLine(seconds + " Seconds");
```

Or using a `StringBuilder` so you can display it in the `MessageBox`

```
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
int totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
int minutes = totalMinutes % 60;
int totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
int hours = totalHours % 24;
int totalDays = totalHours / 24;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder;

if (totalDays > 0)
{
    builder.Append(totalDays + " Days ");
}
if (totalHours > 0)
{
    builder.Append(hours + " Hours ");
}
if (totalMinutes > 0)
{
    builder.Append(minutes + " Minutes ");
}

builder.Append(seconds + " Seconds");
MessageBox.Show(builder.ToString());
```